# chrome script or CLI to open URL and capture screen

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, screen-capture

I'm trying to write a script (or a CLI command would also work) that does essentially the following:

1. open a browser window of a specific size (given in pixels)
2. open a specific URL in that browser window/tab (either is fine)
3. do a screen capture of that particular URL and save this capture to a file
4. push this jpg/png/whatever file somewhere

I can pretty easily write my own script to handle at least #1 and #4, but from the limited reading I've been doing it looks as if the various chrome extensions and/or scripting capabilities might be capable of doing this all in one shot for me (or maybe everything except #4)

I've got a fair bit of generic programming background, but nothing in the chrome extension/script universe, so that part is pretty opaque to me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the same what http://casperjs.org/ do.

Comment: That may work, although I was looking for something (hopefully) that would work in just a few lines of code/script on a standalone chrome install, rather than interfacing with a more substantial development toolset.